# How was DDoS attack on Dyn made?

Tags: network, ddos, denial-of-service

https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/10/ddos-on-dyn-impacts-twitter-spotify-reddit/#more-36727

A DDoS attack on Dyn, on 21st Oct 2016, caused outages for Twitter, SoundCloud, Spotify, Reddit, etc. on the East Coast of USA.

How was the attack carried out, its type, and other details about it?

Comment: Do you expect us to have more information than currently available in public media? There are no reliable information yet.

Comment: Yeah but when more info does finally show up, and this question gets answered, it will get massive upvotes ;-)

Comment: 20 bucks on a Mirai variant. 20 Canadian dollars though...

Answer (score 1):

[Ecuador's](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/julian-assange-eucador-internet-connection-us-election-a7368836.html) government confirms that they cut Julian Assange's Internet connection, after another batch of email exchanges (involves Ms Hillary Clinton) was leaked by Wikileaks, at its embassy in London. 
As per news, the DDoS attack was generated to take revenge for this.

Wikileaks requested the attackers to stop the DDoS attack immediately.

**Type of attack**
Latest reports indicate that the DDoS attack on Dyn infrastructure (particularly DNS servers) was generated using infected IoT devices (like CCTVs, WebCam and others).
The source code of one such malware named **Mirai** was released on the Internet recently. It is speculated that this malware was used for generating the attack.

Comment: Would such an opensource alone be sufficient to launch the attack? (I guess no, for otherwise there would be a real catastrophe.)

Comment: `Mirai` was one of the confirmed malware which was used to launch an attack on Dyn Infrastructure on Fri 21. There may be other malware (or other methods) but those were not confirmed by Dyn (or other security researchers).

Comment: My ignorant's conjecture is that that malware code is apprently not self-sufficient for achieving the reported success. For otherwise any kids would now be able to generate chaos on the Internet.

Comment: They are. in the post releasing the source code, the user anna_senpai claims that at release the bot pulls 300k devices from telnet alone, but it's dropping. Conservatively assuming these can output 1Mb/s, they can deliver a 300Gb/s DDoS